# Perform bulk data insert from multiple tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, performance

Please do advice the best way to perform the bulk data load from multiple tables to single table.

Need to pivot the data from two tables compare the same with third table and load the data to fourth table.

Comment: On a side note: could you explain what is a purpose of this comparison: `TO_CHAR(PSDTE,'YYYYMM')= 'DATAMIGRDTE'` ? It apears to be always false, but could be that I am wrong.

Comment: DATAMIGRDTE is date which we define in our job

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Then a first change would be rewriting all of these conditions: `TO_CHAR(DHD.PSDTE,'YYYYMM')= 'DATAMIGRDTE'` into `DHD.PSDTE >= to_date( 'DATAMIGRDTE', 'yyyymm' ) and DHD.PSDTE <  to_date( 'DATAMIGRDTE', 'yyyymm' ) + interval '1' month`, because the actual form prevents Oracle from using indexes on `PSDTE` column (if such an index is created). Please also run a command `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR insert ..... rest of your query here ....` and then `SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAIN.DISPLAY )`, then copy a result of last query **as a text** and append it to the question.

Comment: Query undergoes full table scan and not the index scan. Have tried giving INDEX hint and no use